# Boundary condition of lookback option

Tags: derivatives, exotics, differential-equations

This is a well know conclusion of the `boundary condition` of `lookback option`. Here
$$\dfrac{d S_t}{S_t} = (\mu - D)dt + \sigma dW_t$$
is `underlying asset`.
$$M_t^{(n)} =\left[\int^t_0S^n_u d u\right]^{\dfrac{1}{n}}$$
$$M_t = \max\limits_{t_0\leq u \leq t}S_u$$
is `maximal process` of $S_t,$ and we have the conclusion:
$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}M_t^{(n)} = M_t$$
$V(S_t,t,M_t)$ is the price of `lookback option` at time $t.$

One of the `boundary condition` of `PDE` for $V$ is
$$\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial M_t}\big|_{S_t = M_t} = 0$$
this is to make the $d M_t$ term zero.

But, some books explain this condition as following way, do you think it is reasonable?
[image]